# Kinect Background Removal with smoothing of an acquired image

Tags: c#, c++, windows-runtime, kinect, kinect-sdk

I have implemented background removal(aka:Green Screen Effect) using Kinect for windows V2 in Windows-RT C# platform.

Now it's working fine for me but the issue I'm facing is with noise, when i mapping color co-ordinate to depth co-ordinate it's very noisy.

I have option to go through the Open-CV but for use Open-CV i need to convert my application in Native(C++) application.

Also another option is with Emgu-CV which are wrapper of the Open-CV for C#. But it not support in the windows-RT.

So Any another solution for the smoothing of Kinect acquired object.

Answer (score 1):

With OpenCV you will also get noise: it's caused by Kinect's precission, not by the API. Try Microsoft's background removal API, they have implemented a smoothing function that greatly improves the results.

On MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn435663.aspx.

There is a sample on the Kinect SDK as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn435686.aspx.

Comment: Hi José Ernesto Lara Rodríguez !!! Thanks for your support but BackGround Removal API is only available for the Kinect 1.8 SDK & currently I'm using Kinect 2.0 SDK which is only supporting the latest Kinect For Windows V2 Device. & Inside the Kinect 2.0 SDK Background Removal API is not available.